# Create Instance of Object by Classname in C++

Tags: c++, reflection, instance, classloader

i'm looking for a solution of my actual problem.
Lets say, i have something like a header file named `Module` with some virtual methods and i have some specific implementations `Module1`, `Module2`, ..., `ModuleN` based on `Module`.

Is there a possibility to create a class instance from the class name?
Lets say, i want to create an instance from `ModuleK` :

```
Module m = Loader.createInstance("ModuleK");
```

or something...

Comment: You need to use the [Factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: @Ron i would like to know, if there are possibilities to create object instances by classname, like in java (with the classloader). 
Im not drawing parallels between java and c++, i'm only asking for the possibility.

Comment: Factory method and also just simply creating subclasses unless Im mistaken in what you are trying to do? If you dont know what the difference between Module and the ModuleK then perhaps passing in that difference using a template is what you are looking for. The Questions does need more clarifying

Comment: Use `std::map<string, function_pointer>`.  The problem is that function pointers need to have the same signature (number and types of parameters as well as return type>.  This is why the Factory Design pattern uses a common base class.

Comment: @Brainfail There is no built-in mechanism to achieve this. You would need to implement a system yourself.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux ahhh okay... :/